# java awt event queue/dispatch thread unknown source errors?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I tried to run this code to make an image using `JFrame`

**Main class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("kek");

        f.add (new GraphicsSurface());

        f.setSize(512, 512);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**GraphicsSurface class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class GraphicsSurface extends JComponent {

    public GraphicsSurface() {
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        int end = 0;
        long redint = 0, greenint = 0, blueint = 0;
        int xstart = 0, ystart = 0, xend = 0, yend = 0;
        double y = 0, x = 0;
        double width = 80;
        double angle = 0;
        double endpoint = 255;
        double curveintensitya = 1.4, curveintensityb = -0.9;
        double curvestarta = 30, curvestartb = 150;
        double curvelengtha = 15, curvelengthb = 30;
        double redvalue = 0, greenvalue = 0, bluevalue = 0;
        while (end == 0) {          

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;            
            redvalue = 100 + (y / 2.56);
            greenvalue = 50 + (y / 1.28);
            bluevalue = 200 + (y / 5.12);
            redint = Math.round(redvalue);
            greenint = Math.round(greenvalue);
            blueint = Math.round(bluevalue);

            if (y >= curvestarta && y < (curvestarta + curvelengtha)) {
                angle = angle + (curveintensitya / curvelengtha);
            }
            if (y >= curvestartb && y < (curvestartb + curvelengthb)) {
                angle = angle + (curveintensityb / curvelengthb);
            }

            width = width + angle;
            if (width > 512) {
                width = 512;
            }
            x = Math.round(width);
            xend = (int) x;
            ystart = (int) y;
            yend = ystart;
            y = y + 1;

            if (y > endpoint) {
                end = 1;
            }

            g2d.setColor(new Color(redint, greenint, blueint, 255));

            g2d.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, yend);
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this in the console:

```
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'd like to know what caused the problem and what I should do to fix it.

Comment: Off-topic: 1) You shouldn't override `paint()` method but `paintComponent()` instead. See [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). 2) Instead of setting frame's preferred size give your component a preferred size by overriding `getPreferredSize()` method. 3) Swing components must be created/updated in the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Initial Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this line

```
g2d.setColor(new Color(redint, greenint, blueint, 255));
```

The type of **redint, greenint** and **blueint** in your code is of type `long`. But the constructor for `Color` takes in either `int` or `long`.

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

So the fix to your problem: change these types from `long` to `int` and do appropriate casting.